# Edge becomes vertex

Tags: graph-theory

I have a graph G. I convert each edge to a vertex and connect this new vertex to the two vertices which were connected by the original edge. Is there a well known graph that represents this kind of transformation?

Answer (score 1):

This is what is known as [the subdivision graph.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_(graph_theory)#Subdivision_and_smoothing)